# Como fazer elemento aparecer após scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Quero fazer um efeito simples, que seria aplicar um efeito de `animate` em uma `div`, aumentando a altura dela após rolagem da página e, quando a página rolasse para o topo novamente, essa `div` voltaria ao style inicial.

### CSS

```
 <style>
  .geral-boxes{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
  }
  .box1,.box2,.box3{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      height: 500px;
  }
  .box1{
      background-color: #fff;
  }
  .box2{
      background-color: #fff;
  }.box3{
      background-color: #fff;
  }
  .geral-boxes{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
  }
  .laranja{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
  }
  .scroll-aparecer{
      width: 50px;
      float: left;
      height: 0px;
      background-color: #000;
  }
```

### SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('.scroll-aparecer').animate({
            height:"100px"
        }, 1000); /*Defina aqui o tempo em milisegundos */
    }else{
        $('.scroll-aparecer').animate({
            height:"0"
        }, 1000); /*Defina aqui o tempo em milisegundos */
    }

  });
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="box1"></div>

<div class="box2"></div>

<div class="box3"></div>

<div class="scroll-aparecer"></div>
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

É preciso usar o método `.stop()` do jQuery para parar a animação quando o `scroll` atender a uma das condições, caso contrário vai dar conflito nas animações quando uma ainda não tiver sido terminada no tempo definido. É como se "jogasse" uma animação em cima da outra que ainda está sendo executada.

Basta adicionar `$('.scroll-aparecer').stop();` no início do evento `scroll`, que irá parar animação do elemento com a classe `.scroll-aparecer` e iniciar ou continuar novamente de acordo com a condição `if`.

No exemplo abaixo coloquei a `div` fixa para que possa visualizar o efeito melhor:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      $('.scroll-aparecer').stop();
      if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
         $('.scroll-aparecer').animate({
            height:"100px"
         }, 1000); /*Defina aqui o tempo em milisegundos */
      }else{
         $('.scroll-aparecer').animate({
         height:"0"
         }, 1000); /*Defina aqui o tempo em milisegundos */
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.geral-boxes{
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}
.box1,.box2,.box3{
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   height: 500px;
}
.box1{
   background-color: #fff;
}
.box2{
   background-color: #fff;
}.box3{
   background-color: #fff;
}
.geral-boxes{
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}
.laranja{
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}
.scroll-aparecer{
   width: 50px;
   float: left;
   height: 0;
   background-color: #000;
   
   position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">Role para baixo</div>

<div class="box2"></div>

<div class="box3"></div>

<div class="scroll-aparecer"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Existe uma forma de fazer esse scroll não pegar a distância do topo da página e sim se referir a algum elemento?

Comment: @maiquel sim, basta pegar a distância do elemento que vc quer se referir até o topo + a altura dele. Veja se é isto: https://jsfiddle.net/pzeemo0f/

Comment: @maiquel Se achou a resposta útil, não deixe de marcar ✔

Answer (score 1):

Percebi alguns erros de sintaxe e nomenclatura no seu código, usando só o scroll eu não consegui obtive o resultado esperado, apenas utilizando um timeout para detectar o fim do scroll, então a animação está sendo executada depois que o scroll é finalizalidado. Também mudei alguns detalhes no css, mas só para facilitar a visualização. Veja se partindo desse ponto você consegue obter o resultado esperado. :)

```js
var espera = 100;
var timeout = null;

$(window).bind('scroll',function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){

    if($(window).scrollTop() > 200)
    {
        $('.scroll-aparecer').animate({ height:"100px" });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.scroll-aparecer').animate({height:"0"});
    }    
    

    },espera);
});
```

```css
.geral-boxes{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
  }
  .box1,.box2,.box3{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      height: 500px;
  }
  .box1{
      background-color: #eee;
  }
  .box2{
      background-color: #bbb;
  }.box3{
      background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .geral-boxes{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
  }
  .laranja{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
  }

  .scroll-aparecer{
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      height: 0px;
      background-color: #000;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1"></div>

<div class="box2"></div>

<div class="box3"></div>

<div class="scroll-aparecer"></div>
```

Comment: Alguns detalhes que eu mencionei sobre sintaxe e nomenclatura foram editados enquanto eu montava a resposta, desconsidere essas observações.

Comment: @maiquel Era isso que você queria?

Comment: Opa, ajudou. Porém eu não queria que a div que aparece ficasse fixa, queria que se posicionasse como outros elementos e rolasse junto com a página. É possível?

Comment: Sim... como eu falei deixei fíxa só para ajudar na visualização do exemplo

Comment: Sim, como eu falei, deixei fixa para facilitar a visualização do exemplo